# Installing pdfgrep on windows server

Tags: pdf, grep, windows-server-2008

I am trying to install the `pdfgrep` command line utility on a Windows Server 2008 R2 from  [this sources](http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/pdfgrep-windows-version) unfortunaly, I had no idea about what to do with those source files after download it so i seach on stackoverflow related problem and i found a ticket who tell to install `cygwin`, I have done that but when I make the `./configure`, it doesn't  work, here are the output I get:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/Administrateur/pdfgrep-1.2':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

So what I still have to install for this to work ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for the useless question, I found it by myself, I just rerun cygwin installer and select a c++ compile before reinstall

Answer (score 3):

I know the user found a solution but I didn't have the option of installing Cygwin (for reasons...) and i found a simple solution. 
Note: I am running windows 10, so this might not work for Windows below 7.

All you need to do is extract the folder and then go to `DOS` or command prompt.
There are two ways to go about it now.

1. Go to the folder itself and run it from there

```
cd C:\to\where\the\folder\is
pdfgrep -i keyword1|keyword2|etc C:\wherever\the\file\is.pdf
```

OR
2. run code directly from where ever you are in command prompt

```
C:\to\where\the\folder\is\pdfgrep -i keyword1|keyword2|etc C:\wherever\the\file\is.pdf
```

the `-i` is ignore case (one of pdfgrep options).

Hopefully this helps out other people